# T-SQL XML Value/Nodes functions + XML Cast

Tags: xml, t-sql

I have a column in table which contains XML text, but it is not XML type and its type should not be changed.

I have write the following SQL query to get some information from its

```
DECLARE @TempXML XML=(SELECT TOP 1 XMLColumn FROM TableOne)

SELECT  T.c.query('.').value('(/question/@id)[1]','BIGINT') AS [QuestionID]
       ,T.c.query('.').value('(/question/@comment)[1]','NVARCHAR(100)') AS [Comment]
       ,T.c.query('.').value('(/question/answer/@pos)[1]','TINYINT') AS [AnswerPosition]
FROM   @TempXML.nodes('/submission/question') T(c)
```

The problem I have net is that I have to create a view in which for each row the query above will be executed, but I am not able to concatenated the query and the xml conversion.

I have try to create CTE in which to do the conversion but then met some difficulties 
 in implementing my query.

```
WITH CTEview(CurrentXML) AS 
(
    SELECT CAST(XMLColumn AS XML) AS [CurrentXML]
    FROM TableOne
)
--My SQL goes here
```

Comment: Wow, I have done this by a change adding using Cross Apply with the XML column from the CTE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using "Cross Apply" to the XML columns from the CTE solve the issue.